# NullPointerException caught when joining two dataset

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, dataset, birt

I am a BIRT newbie and am using Eclipse Neon1.a.

I tried to join two simple data sets off an XML data source, but getting this error immediately after I clicked Finish.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by:

- Removing the beforeOpen script under the ODA Data Source(Data Source)
- Removing the default Report Parameter